# Partial refresh of menu in customizer not working?

Tags: menus, theme-customizer

WordPress 4.5 supposedly enables live refresh of the menu in the customizer, though I cannot get it to work.

If I reorder the menu (in customizer) I see no changes until I perform a manual refresh. However, if I click the Menu Locations checkbox to disable the menu, and again to re-enable, the screen does refresh. Though doing that saves the menu - which is not ideal. Or is that the intended functionality?

Clicking save and publish does not trigger a refresh either. Since other changes in customizer are shown in real time, this seems inconsistent.

Has anyone gotten this to work?

Comment: I haven't got across this new feature yet, but for clarification, are you developing a theme? Or using an existing one? If so, is this a built in theme or third party? If you're developing, please show the code you're using to attempt to make it work.

Comment: It is a custom theme. I am using the default menu customizer (not making any changes to default functionality). Menu is pretty standard:

$args = array(
                'menu'      => "Primary",
                'depth'     =>  2,
                'container' => 'nav',
                'fallback_cb' => '',
                'container_class' => 'visible-large primary-menu'

            );
            wp_nav_menu( $args );

Comment: Isn't selective refresh opt in? See https://make.wordpress.org/core/2016/02/16/selective-refresh-in-the-customizer/

Comment: For menus selective refresh should be default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem - it was stupid but I hope this helps someone.

I had set the menu using the "menu" arg like so:

```
 $args = array(
            'menu'   => "Primary", 
  );
```

For selective refresh to work, you have to use the "theme_location" arg like so:

```
 $args = array(
            'theme_location'   => "primary", 
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

Selective refresh is only for the items that are selected to cause auto refresh in customizer as explained here:

https://make.wordpress.org/core/2016/02/16/selective-refresh-in-the-customizer/

and here:

https://make.wordpress.org/core/2016/03/22/implementing-selective-refresh-support-for-widgets/

So if the theme developer haven't included this support then you might not see it refresh automatically on save and publish of menu items.

Comment: As of 4.5 selective refresh is supposed to be enabled by default on menus in customizer - and theme support is also default.

Comment: yes but you might still need to add code for it, check this: https://make.wordpress.org/core/2016/03/22/implementing-selective-refresh-support-for-widgets/